# Cannot change windows update settings(despite being administrator)

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

I cannot change windows update settings for my computer despite being administrator of computer.
The dropdown list is greyed out.
I am running Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: Is this your notebook or a work notebook? If it is a work one it could be controlled by a group policy setting. You should however be able to click the button that says check for updates anyways or something to that effect.

Comment: No. Its my personal desktop at home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/windows-7-64-bit-windows-updates-grayed-out/23a5eb7c-bb70-4f98-b1cb-bb31fd2d60b8

If you have uninstalled any antivirus software recently (specifically McAfee/Norton), see if the vendor provides a special complete removal tool. Google will help here.

Visit this site: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058
Internet Explorer (32-bit) is recommended, but not necessary. Other browsers just download an executable file as far as I can tell.

Now, according to the source, you should run the fix it tool first in default then in aggressive mode. Personally, it didn't give me that option, but just run it and see how it goes.

There are also alternative instructions on the KB article if you do not wish to run the fix it tool.

Comment: Ouch, formatting in a quote is a pain. And I've just realised the whole list of instructions is useless if the KB article containing downloads for the Windows Update Agent disappears anyway, so I'll edit out that quote in a minute.